How i can use switch case statement in cdap studio pipeline
i have two table and i want to assign value in one table row on the basis of value present in anothher table .
i used switch case in sql but how i can achieve same thing in cdap studio.
more explaination of question
I have two tables:
Table A
(to check if a value is present) and
Table B
(where you want to assign values based on the condition).
Scenario:
Suppose we have the following requirements:
Table A
contains student scores, and we want to determine their grades.
We’ll use the
Switch Case transform
to assign grades based on the score.
The assigned grades will be stored in
Table B
